# disadvantages of using too many sessions in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, session

In ASP.NET, sessions enable us to store and retrieve values for a user as the user navigates ASP.NET pages in a web application. However, using too much sessions is discouraged. Why? What are the disadvantages of using too many sessions?

Thanks for those who will answer.

Comment: There is a similar question in this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799175/asp-net-masters-what-are-the-advantages-disadvantages-of-using-session-variab

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Memory and/or performance

If you store session state in-process (the default), all of your session data are stored in the app pool's local memory.  If you have thousands of users you can see why this may be a problem.   The problem gets worse when developers don't remove session variables after they're no longer needed (this is very common due to the fact that it's very hard to control the order in which web pages are accessed) and/or when users do not explicitly logout (e.g. by closing the browser window), which leaves all this memory still allocated but no longer used.

If you store session state out of process (e.g. in SQL Server or a separate state server), all of the session variables end up crossing the wire.  As you add more variables, more and more data have to get pulled over.  This can end up degrading performance.

### Concurrency

If a web application uses session state, the data in which the session state is accessed has to be protected from race conditions and other multithreading concerns.  As a result, ASP.NET automatically serializes any requests that use session.  If you send two requests at the same time, ASP won't even start on the second request until the first one is finished.  This can cause unexpected and poor performance on applications that use a lot of AJAX or other logic that is supposed to be asynchronous.

### Infrastructure

If you're using local memory for session state, and your web app is load balanced, the load balancer must enforce session stickiness, either with IP address or a cookie.  This constrains the load balancer in the way it can handle requests-- all requests for a certain session always hit the same server-- which reduces overall performance and eliminates redundancy.

### Loss of data

If the app pool recycles, all sessions running on that app pool lose session state, often requiring users to log out and start over.

### Poor code design

Session variables are essentially global variables.  Overuse of global variables tends to lead to sloppy code structure.  Variables should always be scoped as tightly as possible.

Comment: Great answer and good coverage, I'm removing my answer as this covers my point as well. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it consumes server memory. As generally sessions are stored in process, this solution doesn't scale well, as can't be shared between two or more state servers.